# R Metaprogramming: return function body with arguments values filled in

Tags: r, metaprogramming, rlang

I am looking for a function that will return the body of function with the arguments filled in. The goal is to have a function, `capture_code` such that

```
my_scatterplot <- function(my_title, xlab = "mpg", ylab = "hp") {
  g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
    geom_point()
  g + labs(x = xlab, y = ylab, title = my_title)
}

capture_code(my_scatterplot("My title", xlab = "MPG"))
```

Will return

```
  g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
    geom_point()
  g + labs(x = "MPG", y = ylab, title = "My title")
```

I am using the code from [advanced R Walking AST with recursive functions](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html#ast-funs).

```
expr_type <- function(x) {
  if (rlang::is_syntactic_literal(x)) {
    "constant"
  } else if (is.symbol(x)) {
    "symbol"
  } else if (is.call(x)) {
    "call"
  } else if (is.pairlist(x)) {
    "pairlist"
  } else {
    typeof(x)
  }
}

switch_expr <- function(x, ...) {
  switch(expr_type(x),
         ...,
         stop("Don't know how to handle type ", typeof(x), call. = FALSE)
  )
}

replace_vars <- function(x, envi) {
  switch_expr(x,
              # Base cases
              constant = x,
              symbol = {
                # Get the variable from the environment
                rlang::env_get(nm = as.character(x), default = x, env = envi)
              },

              # Recursive cases
              pairlist = purrr::map(x, replace_vars, envi),
              call = {
                res <- purrr::map(x, replace_vars, envi)
                class(res) <- class(x)
                res
              }
  )
}

capture_code <- function(e) {
  e <- rlang::enexpr(e)
  cf <- get(toString(e[[1]]))
  if(typeof(cf) != "closure") stop(e[[1]], "is not a function")

  # Evalation the named functions first
  # Then fill in the unnamed
  cf_args <- formals(cf)
  called_args <- as.list(e[-1])
  if(!is.null(names(called_args))) {
    not_named <- names(called_args) == ""
    named_args <- called_args[!not_named]
    unnamed_args <-  called_args[not_named]

    new_args <- modifyList(cf_args, named_args)
    missing_args <- unlist(lapply(new_args, rlang::is_missing))
    missing_indices <- seq_along(new_args)[missing_args]
  } else {
    new_args <- cf_args
    unnamed_args <- called_args
    missing_indices <- seq_along(new_args)
  }

  # Add the unnamed arguments
  for(i in seq_along(unnamed_args)) {
    new_args[[missing_indices[[i]]]] <- unnamed_args[[i]]
  }

  # Get the function body from
  cf_func_body <- functionBody(cf)[-1]

  # Pass the arguments as an environment for lookup
  replace_vars(cf_func_body, rlang::new_environment( as.list(new_args)))
}

res <- capture_code(my_scatterplot("My title", xlab = "MPG"))
res
```

I have included the View call from the function body expression as well as my results. It looks almost correct, except I am unable to get the `call` and `<-` classes to be of type `language`. I would like to be able to get back the code from my AST.

[image: View(cf_func_body]

[image: View(res)]

Comment: is there a use case to this or is it just a puzzle ? because what you're trying to do here wouldn't be efficient, nor necessarily correct, if given arguments were variable or expressions rather than string litterals. Think of the case where you'd have an argument `i = i +1` that would be substituted several times, or just `i=j` with `j` modified in the function's body before `i` 's definition is called.

Comment: The use case was to be able to return the code produced by a plot creating in a function in a shiny application. Something like shinymeta, except that I have one function that creates multiple plots. I am leaving this question as is, but it actually doesn't solve the use case I described due to the variables not showing their values.

Comment: maybe the package oshka will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the call into `mc` and extract the function `fun`.  Then wrap its body in `substitute(...)`, replace the function name in the call with `fun` and run it.  No packages are used.

```
capture_code <- function(call) {
  mc <- match.call()[[2]]
  fun <- match.fun(mc[[1]])
  body(fun) <- substitute(substitute(b), list(b = body(fun)))
  mc[[1]] <- as.name("fun")
  eval(mc)
}

# test
capture_code(my_scatterplot("My title", xlab = "MPG"))
```

giving:

```
{
    g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + geom_point()
    g + labs(x = "MPG", y = "hp", title = "My title")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mildly-hacky approach:

```r
library(rlang)

my_scatterplot <- function(my_title, xlab = "mpg", ylab = "hp") {
    g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
        geom_point()
    g + labs(x = xlab, y = ylab, title = my_title)
}

capture_code <- function(call){
    call <- call_standardise(enquo(call))    # capture call and fill in params and default args
    args <- call_args(call)    # extract cleaned args
    body <- fn_body(call_fn(call))    # extract function body

    eval(substitute(substitute(body, args)))    # substitute args in body
}

capture_code(my_scatterplot("My title", xlab = "MPG"))
#> {
#>     g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + geom_point()
#>     g + labs(x = "MPG", y = ylab, title = "My title")
#> }
```

The hacky bit is the last line, which uses `substitute` to replace parameters with arguments wherever they are within the function body. As far as I can tell, there's no simple way to do this with rlang, because the quosure idiom requires you to specify exactly what you'd like to substitute; `base::substitute` is more of a shotgun approach.

You can also use `pryr::modify_lang`, which traverses the AST like you've started writing above:

```r
capture_code <- function(call){
    call <- call_standardise(enquo(call))
    args <- call_args(call)
    body <- fn_body(call_fn(call))

    pryr::modify_lang(body, function(leaf){
        expr_string <- expr_name(leaf)
        if (expr_string %in% names(args)) {
            args[[expr_string]]
        } else {
            leaf
        }
    })
}

capture_code(my_scatterplot("My title", xlab = "MPG"))
#> {
#>     g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + geom_point()
#>     g + labs(x = "MPG", y = ylab, title = "My title")
#> }
```

Look at its source code if to see how to structure the recursion, but note that there are some weird bits of the language you have to account for to do this right.

If you want to roll your own recursion, ignoring the weirder bits (like formulas, pairlists, etc.) that won't matter for this call anyway,

```r
capture_code <- function(call){
    call <- call_standardise(enquo(call))
    args <- call_args(call)
    body <- fn_body(call_fn(call))

    modify_expr <- function(node){
        node_string <- expr_name(node)
        if (length(node) > 1) {
            node <- lapply(node, modify_expr)    # recurse
            as.call(node)
        } else if (node_string %in% names(args)) {
            args[[node_string]]    # substitute
        } else {
            node    # ignore
        }
    }
    modify_expr(body)
}

capture_code(my_scatterplot("My title", xlab = "MPG"))
#> {
#>     g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + geom_point()
#>     g + labs(x = "MPG", y = ylab, title = "My title")
#> }
```